# Making this jquery bulk checkbox ticker more generic

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have created a JQuery routine to check all the checkboxes on a page using a master checkbox.

I am generally happy with this function and it is serving me well but it is not very generic and I have now copy/pasted it into a number of pages in my solution.

I also have a couple of pages where I have copy/pasted it twice because I have two groups of checkboxes on one page that need to be controlled independently. This is not good!

I would really love to genericise this and stuff it away in my main .js script file but I do not know where to start! I would love to be able to use a system of classes to tell JQuery which set of checkboxes is controlled by which master checkbox.

Can you help please? I feel that a solution would boost my jquery ability massively!

(n.b. please excuse the classes in  tags, that is down to the nasty way that asp.net renders checkboxes)

```js
$(function () {
  $(".checkAllLeft").click(function () {
    if ($(".checkAllLeft").is(':checked')) {
      $(".LeftCheckbox").each(function () {
        var checkbox = $(this).find("input")
        if (checkbox.prop("disabled") == false) { checkbox.prop("checked", true); }
      });

    } else {
      $(".LeftCheckbox").each(function () {
        var checkbox = $(this).find("input")
        if (checkbox.prop("disabled") == false) { checkbox.prop("checked", false); }
      });
    }
  });
});

$(function () {
  $(".checkAllRight").click(function () {
    if ($(".checkAllRight").is(':checked')) {
      $(".RightCheckbox").each(function () {
        var checkbox = $(this).find("input")
        if (checkbox.prop("disabled") == false) { checkbox.prop("checked", true); }
      });

    } else {
      $(".RightCheckbox").each(function () {
        var checkbox = $(this).find("input")
        if (checkbox.prop("disabled") == false) { checkbox.prop("checked", false); }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Check All Left<br /><input type="checkbox" class="checkAllLeft"></td>
    <td>Check All Right<br /><input type="checkbox" class="checkAllRight"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="LeftCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" ></span></td>
    <td><span class="RightCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" ></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="LeftCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" ></span></td>
    <td><span class="RightCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" ></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="LeftCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" ></span></td>
    <td><span class="RightCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" ></span></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use DOM traversal to find all the checkboxes within the same container (ie. the same column) as the 'check all' option, then set them to the same value. Something like this:

```js
$(".check-all").change(function() {
  var tdIndex = $(this).closest('td').index() + 1;
  $('table tr td:nth-child(' + tdIndex + ') :checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Check All Left<br /><input type="checkbox" class="check-all" /></td>
    <td>Check All Right<br /><input type="checkbox" class="check-all" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span><input type="checkbox" /></span></td>
    <td><span><input type="checkbox" /></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span><input type="checkbox" /></span></td>
    <td><span><input type="checkbox" /></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span><input type="checkbox" /></span></td>
    <td><span><input type="checkbox" /></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There's a couple of other things to note. Firstly, you don't need to use a document.ready event per function call; you can place all logic within a single one. Secondly the `border` attribute on `table` elements is very outdated. Use CSS instead.

Comment: I'm not sure that this DOM traversal is what I am after, the checkboxes will exist in a table in a column. I will quickly re-fiddle my js fiddle.

Yeh, the border is bad. I wanted a quick and dirty way to visually separate the two sets of chex!

Comment: DOM traversal is exactly what you need to make the code DRY. Just the methods may change depending on how your DOM is structured.

Comment: Right o! Can you think of a DOM traversal way to do the re-structured fiddle? I'm going to go and have a think too it will be something to do with using the classes on the span tags to work from the originally checked box.

Sorry to pull the rug from your original response too! It was a spot on suggestion for the original example.

Comment: Thats corking, i'm going to bone up on my selector syntax methinks! That has also solved the dreadful checkbox rendering issue too. Cheers!